# Dual boot issue with windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a windows 10 system. Installation was successful, but after rebooting the system, it is taking me directly to windows OS. GRUB menu is not getting loaded during the boot.

I have tried EasyBCD software also but it says the following,

> EasyBCD has detected that your machine is currently booting in EFI
>   mode. Due to limitations set by Microsoft, many of EasyBCD's
>   multi-booting features cannot be used in EFI mode and have been
>   disabled

How do I add Ubuntu entry to Bootloader and make it dual boot?

Comment: Please launch a Linux live disk and run [Boot Info Script.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) This will create a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post it to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post a link to your document here. That will provide us with more information about your configuration, without which any answer will be largely guesswork. Also, please tell us the make and model of your computer; that information may be relevant, too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, here's the link for the file created after running the Boot Fixer > http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14600187/

Also, my laptop model is HP Pavillion G6 Notebook 64-bit and Bios is F.27

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr. You may also want to look into the [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) Windows program.