# Should Ubuntu or Fedora be installed first for dual boot?

Tags: boot, fedora

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 (BIOS boot). I want to set up my computer for EFI booting, dual booting into Ubuntu and Fedora. Any thoughts on which OS I should install first? Also, since I have never dual booted before, will the computer name be that of the first install, or will it depend on which OS is running?

Answer (score 3):

Install Ubuntu last so that Ubuntu uses its own Grub bootloader. The Fedora Project releases a new version of Fedora approximately every 6 months and provides updated packages to these releases for approximately 13 months, while Ubuntu LTS releases are supported for 5 years, so the OS with the longer term of support should be installed last in order for it to use its own bootloader. The Ubuntu installer prompts you to select a computer name and so does the Fedora installer, so there can be different computer names for each of the two OSs in the dual boot and which computer name is used depends on which OS is running.

Comment: With UEFI you have slightly more choices. With BIOS there was only one MBR. With UEFI each install has boot files in ESP - efi system partition and you can choose any system from UEFI boot menu. Or change default boot with efibootmgr or from inside UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr See also `man efibootmgr`