# Dual Boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 Troubles

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, grubrescue

System:

MSI X370 Sli 
Ryzen 7
32GB DDR4 Ram

1TB HD << this is where windows is already installed
500GB SSD << where I try to get Ubuntu

I tried to create a dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu the following way:

I first installed Windows 10 on my HD. I then created a bootable USB with Ubuntu 16.04 on it (using Rufus). I then booted with the USB in and selected boot from USB.

In the Ubuntu installation menu I choose "Select something else" and then created two partitions on the SSD (previously made that disk unallocated space in windows). I installed Ubuntu onto a 32GB partition within there and selected the boot information to be installed there too.

I have the following trouble: 
if I select bootorder HD > SSD > ... , when I boot the PC and don't hit anything during booting, it just goes straight to Windows 10. (as expected)

if I select boot order SSD > HD >... , it gives me Grub Rescue, as i386-pc/normal.mod cannot be found. I checked all ubuntu questions on this and they all say to "find it manually" and it just does not exist anywhere navigating with Grub Rescue!

Further: if I hit a key to get to UEFI (F11 in this case), I am given the option to:
- boot with Windows boot manager from HD
- boot with Ubuntu from HD
- boot from HD
- boot from SSD

If I select the first, I get Windows. If I select the second, I get Ubuntu. If I select the third, I get Windows. If I select the last, I get the Grub Rescue error as above.

My question now: is Ubuntu actually installed on the HD??? It doesn't show up anywhere when I check in windows.. 
Further, how do I get to choose what to boot during booting without having to hit F11 the half second time frame that it gives me this option?

Comment: Yes, apperently it is installed where you wanted it to be: *boot with Ubuntu from HD* . Linux partitions are not visible in Windows (without a special and absolutely NOT RECOMMENDED software). Your second question stems from a probably "incorrect" installation of Ubuntu/dualboot. This is what you need to know in order to work with UEFI machines: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: In UEFI mode grub only installs to ESP - efi system partition on drive seen as sda. You should be able to set Ubuntu as first in UEFI boot order and from grub boot Windows. But grub only boots working Windows that is not hibernated (fast boot on) nor if Windows needs chkdsk. Then you need to either direct boot windows or use your Windows repair flash drive.Boot order: http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Comment: Chances are you need to [disable Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [disable Hibernate](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) in Windows, and maybe do a `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu afterwards. If that doesn't help, run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here.