# Ubuntu bootloader turned into Debian

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

[image: This was purple, regular ubuntu style.]

[image: Result of boot-repair-disk-]

Last thing i remember is that i uninstalled python from ubuntu system(Which I will never attempt to do it again).
If I enter Debian GNU/Linux, it leads me to virtual terminal.
I also have Windows 10, so how could I reverse this issue?

Comment: You have UEFI boot, and it just looks like you changed default boot to Debian. Or installed Debian last it made  itself first in boot order. All systems do that. You should just need to change boot order to make Ubuntu first. You may be able to do that in UEFI, you could boot Ubuntu and reinstall its grub. But probably easiest just to use efibootmgr to change boot order. see also 
`man efibootmgr` & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Comment: I changed the order, but I guess ubuntu grub was corrupted, and nothing worked no matter how many times i try to repair grub. As a last resort, I booted into a live usb and reinstalled ubuntu without deleting personal files.
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you reinstall python. And it probably break some Ubuntu packages.
I solved it by reinstalling ubuntu-desktop. So after logging in the command line, install this.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```