# Grub disappeared after Python 3 removal

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, python

Grub has disappeared.

A few days ago, I removed Python 3 and that screwed up the whole Ubuntu graphical interface.  I fixed this by reinstalling `Ubuntu-desktop`.

However, the Grub menu does not show up at the machine boot any more, and the PC directly loads Windows.

The following are two screenshots of the current BIOS set-up configuration. It seems to be as it was, but I could be wrong:

[image]
[image]

If, in the boot manager, I chose Ubuntu, the classic purple Grub screen appears and allows me to choose the OS I prefer.

How can I make the Grub show up first again?

Comment: In your first UEFI screen the OS Boot Manager has an arrow. That means multiple entries. If you click on that line you then should be able to change the order inside that. If not you probably can use efibootmgr to change boot order. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Comment: @oldfred I'm able to, but the positions get automatically switched to previous configuration, with Windows on top. Do you know why?

Comment: @oldfred `efibootmgr -o` worked for me! Dual boot is now ok. But, in the BIOS OS options, I still can see Windows on top. How does it work? What does now prevent Windows to be the first loaded if it's on top on BIOS options?

Comment: Windows or UEFI may be switching order. I have seen users post with some systems that the change only stays if they use UEFI to change boot order. My system works fine with efibootmgr, but I do not have Windows. A few older systems boot only by description and only description is "Windows Boot Manager". We then have other work arounds for those.