# How to change default partition on partition boot up disk

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

On bootup, it says:

```
Kubuntu
Ubuntu
```

and boots default Kubuntu.

How do I change the default on the grub boot menu?

Comment: Is that from UEFI boot menu or grub boot menu? UEFI or BIOS. If UEFI and UEFI boot menu, see this: `man efibootmgr` and 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Comment: Grub  boot menu, I am pretty sure.

Comment: Read the `man` pages produced by `man -k grub`.

Comment: You can also boot into Ubuntu and just reinstall grub. But each system with updates may reset it. `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` if BIOS install and drive is sda. If not we need more info. Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Boot into the OS you don't want to boot automatically. Open Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd>

Run in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line GRUB_DEFAULT=0

GRUB_DEFAULT=1

Run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

Edit:

Note:

1. this is for present default OS which you don't want to be default. In your case Kubuntu.
2. For Grub boot menu.
3. When you have two Linux operating systems whenever you or the system updates grub in one OS that becomes the default, so you have to change the priorities every time. By doing the above when Kubuntu updates grub the second choice (that is Ubuntu) is selected.

Comment: Is this on the to-be deafault os, or the other one?

Comment: Havent figured it out @vijay

Comment: @Christopher M See edited answer.

Comment: @Christopher M I still am not sure that you have grub boot menu and not EFI. Please tell about other grub boot entries you see at bootup.

Comment: I was giving an aproxamate answer. It would look more like this:

Comment: `Kubuntu 18.10 LTS`

Comment: `Adcanced options for kubntu`

Comment: e.c.t, `Ubuntu`

Comment: So that should work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87819/discussion-between-christopher-m-and-vijay).