# Update UEFI boot optons from Terminal

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Windows 10 dual boot is causing issues. Windows will forcibly update the boot options to make itself the first boot option AND will delete the entry for grub. I have fixed this in the passed by duplicating the Boot entry for grub in the terminal (after which Windows ignores it but still makes itself king). I have tried looking but cannot find this command anywhere. Does anyone know what the terminal command is to update UEFI boot entries?

Thanks,
Noki

Comment: Ooops, I saved the answer on this very site! I am a fool. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131886/windows-10-overrides-boot-settings-in-uefi-bios-requires-live-cd-fix-to-repair

Comment: See also `man efibootmgr` and you can just change boot order with most systems, some only let you change order from within UEFI settings. http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr and more efibootmgr examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 1):

Go into windows and check if it's booting in Legacy or UEFI mode. I just installed 18.04 as a dual boot to my windows 10 installation yesterday and it was a huge pain because Win10 was booting in Legacy.

To check Win10 boot mode execute:
Windows + R
"msinfo32.exe"
Look for the Bios mode, you should see these settings on your screen
[Windows10 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6oOc.png)

Comment: Windows is using UEFI Mode to boot I have confirmed, logically it would have to be to keep altering the UEFI boot options in my BIOS. Thanks for the suggestion though. I wish there was something to do to fix it.