# Kali & Ubuntu Dual Boot Grub Issue

Tags: dual-boot

After installing Kali Linux, I then shrank the partition and installed Ubuntu on the available space. The problem I'm now getting is when I restart my laptop, the following Kali Linux menu appears with **no** options to boot to Ubuntu:

> - Kali GNU/Linux
> - Advanced options for Kali GNU/Linux
> - System setup

However, when I select *System setup* and then press the *F9* key, I get the following Boot Manager page:

Boot Option Menu:

> - OS boot Manager (UEFI) - Kali (HGST HTS545050A7E680)
> - OS boot Manager (UEFI) - ubuntu (HGST HTS545050A7E680)
> - Boot From EFI File

When i select **OS boot Manager (UEFI) - ubuntu**, the *GNU GRUB version 2.02* menu appears:

> - Ubuntu
> - Advanced options for Ubuntu
> - Kali GNU/Linux Rolling (on /dev/sda2)
> - Advanced options for Kali GNU/Linux Rolling (on /dev/sda2)
> - System setup

**This is the only menu I want to appear when my laptop first boots. How do I fix this?**

EDIT @zerdecal
[image: sudo update-grub]

EDIT 2 @oldfred
[image: sudo efibootmgr -o 0,1]

Comment: You can try changing boot order with efibootmgr: http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr see also: `man efibootmgr`. Some systems like HP may not work with efibootmgr and you have to update UEFI and change UEFI boot order from within UEFI settings. Some with HP  just end up always booting from UEFI boot menu.

Comment: @oldfred thanks for the reply. I changed the boot order using `sudo efibootmgr -o 0,1` but when i restarted the laptop, i'm still getting Kali Linux boot menu. See results in EDIT 2 above. Researching whether I should update the firmware.

Comment: HP UEFI boot order change with efibootmgr does not stick, but change in HP's UEFI does work
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390309
HP X360 Update UEFI F20
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2439220

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: @karel yes it does, thank you very much for sharing! Very detailed and informative answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `update-grub` to see if that will detect Ubuntu. This should check to see what operating systems are installed and update the grub

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ran sudo update-grub. See results in my edit. The problem still persists.

Comment: try to run it from Kali side if you can enter and also grub customizer program might help to add other entry to grub page

Comment: Running `update-grub` in Kali worked. Thanks!