# Clean Ubuntu 20.04 Installation Failure "Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed."

Tags: grub2, system-installation, 20.04

just getting started using Linux here, so sorry if this is a basic question. I have tried a lot of the fixes in similar posts here and on other forums but to no avail. Most refer to dual-boot systems, which mine is not.

I am trying to install Linux on a standalone hard drive in my desktop system. AMD64, Asus B450 mobo, Ryzen 3600, RTX 2070, and a kind of old Hyper X SSD. I was getting some APCI errors, but turned APCI off and that fixed that which allows me to run Ubuntu on my flash drive without issue. It is the only drive on my system and it is completely clean, erased in Gparted before install.

However, whenever I try to install linux on my drive, I keep getting the same error

> Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error.

Sometimes it gives me an error report, other times it does not. I have tried inducing the more detailed error message but haven't succeeded the past few times.

After attempting an install, without quitting the trial, if I run the installer again I get the following error after selecting my installation options (normal vs minimal)

> ubi-partman failed with exit code 10. Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. Do you want to try...

Which points me to a huge log file whose information I can share.

I have set Secure Boot to type "Other OS". Fast Boot is disabled. CSM is enabled and set to UEFI first for all parameters. I have also tried pre-setting the partitions with GParted to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What partition scheme does your disk use? You can find this by running `sudo fdisk -l`, it will either show "dos" (for msdos) or "gpt". When booting through Legacy BIOS mode, msdos is preferred. When booting through UEFI, gpt is preferred. I'd recommend changing the partition table (using Gparted if you wish) to the one most appropriate for you depending on whether you are booting through Legacy or UEFI. Do note that in order to boot via Legacy on a gpt partition table, there must exist a BIOS boot partition at the very start of the disk, of ~1Mb in size, unformatted, and flagged as bios_grub.

Comment: I am using UEFI and GPT. I am not sure what the partition scheme is on the installation media, though I'm not sure that matters.

Comment: I am using this solution [check my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1308005/517399)

Comment: I am using this solution [check my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1308005/517399)

Answer (score 1):

The below steps helped me fix similar failing Ubuntu-20.4 installation on a MacMini2019.

After grub-install fails try this https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/

`grub> set root=(hd0,1)`   "this can be different for you so search partitions to find correct one"

`grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-X.XX.X-XX-generic root=/dev/sda1` "instead of sda1 per the tutorial I gave nvme0n1p2, for you can be nvme0nXpX or sdaX"

```
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-X.XX.X-XX-generic
grub> boot
```

This helped me boot but still had to fix grub. After `apt update` and `apt upgrade` I did the following:
[Change boot order using efibootmgr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr)

```
sudo su
cd /boot/efi/EFI
mv BOOT BOOT_bak
cp -R ubuntu BOOT
cd BOOT
mv shimx64.efi bootx64.efi
```