# Executing 'grub-install' ubuntu 20.04 macbook pro

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, macbook

i try to install ubuntu 20.04 and i partition the disk to swap (16 GB) and ubuntu (50 Gb) and when i want install on hard disk i find this error

> Executing 'grub-install/dev/nvme0n1p5' failed  this is fatal error

i was search for this problem on google but i don't found solution work for me
my laptop is macbook pro 2018

Comment: Check out  the answer to this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256686/cannot-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-mac-mini-2020

Comment: @darth_epoxy is working for me thanks but the problem when i restart the problem come again  what should i do

Comment: What exactly do you see when you reboot? Grub menu? Limited grub terminal? Black screen? Purple screen?

Comment: @darth_epoxy Grub menu that what i see

Comment: So you select Ubuntu from the grub menu and do you then get the desktop login screen or something else?

Comment: @darth_epoxy i get desktop login

Comment: And what is the problem?