# Stuck on initramfs prompt

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

[Booting Normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOGpR.png)

after rebooting system, i am met with the Grub Menu Version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu

selecting Advanced options i can see the latest available kernel is 4.4.0-145-generic
however that provides screenshot 1.

i selected all previous kernels, but the only one in the list that seems to boot is 4.4.0-133-generic.
it loads for about 5minutes on the blue Xubuntu screen, then just errors out to a initramfs command prompt with limited commands.
[INITRAMfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXanq.png)

typing in (initramfs) exit
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket connect failed no such file or directory

then it continues to try to load, but fails back to the initramfs screen
refusing activation of partial LV -vg/root Use "--activate-mode partial" to override

this ubuntu VM exists within our managed services cloud infrastructure but it is not a managed device, and there fore i do not have physical access to this device to try boot media.

is there a way to restore a terminal from the initramfs screen? my research has lead me to believe that the boot partition is filled, or the latest kernel does not have the proper files. looking for best next steps in troubleshooting, unable to find a post exactly related. Thank you in advance

(initramfs) ls

dev kernel usr lib lib64 init run sys tmp
root scripts bin sbin etc var conf proc

(initramfs)

Comment: Did you make any system changes at all immediately prior to this issue happening?  If so, please detail them in your quesiton.  Please also include the version and flavor of Ubuntu you are using. FYI: this can happen if your hard drive is dying.

Comment: From that first teminal you are taken to after booting, please type `ls` and post the result.

Comment: grub> ls  (hd0) (hdo,msdos5) (hdo,msdos3) (hdo,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1) - @darth_epoxy

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer that is posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256686/cannot-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-mac-mini-2020)

Basically you need to find which of those partitions hold your home directory and which one holds your grub and then update your initramfs. There are extensive notes [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392723/trying-to-single-install-on-macbook-pro-but-wont-automatically-boot-from-new-os/550027#550027) but not all of that will apply to your case.