# Boots to grub command line or shows you need to load kernel first message for 4-5 reboots before booting normally

Tags: boot, kubuntu, boot-repair, grub-efi

I know this has been asked a lot of times before and I have tried almost all those fixes the commands like `set root=/dev/nvme0n1p1` always fail tried both boot-repair disk's recommended repair and advanced (only selected to purge grub before reinstalling it)

I have reinstalled OS 3 times with same issue every time, and I tried all the fixes, but everything failed.

Note: it's not dual boot and i have only one nvme ssd

Also when it boots normally or shuts down it displays a black screen for a second which says something like elantech failed to query capabilities

Currently I am on 4th fresh install with the same problem and hv only run boot-repair once. logs- https://paste.debian.net/1211042/

System info:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-34-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz
Memory: 7.4 GiB of RAM
```

Comment: Follow MY Answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256686/cannot-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-mac-mini-2020/1265490#1265490 and yes you have to set ROOT and the RAM like you already have but the trick is, after you get to the >reboot step you MUST fix your grub file or when you reboot it will go back the UUID problem again.

Comment: @darth-epoxy thanks! set root command failed and the ls (hd0,gpt1)/boot/grub says grub folder doesn't exist but the answer below yours seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below, so long as you can make it specifi to your question and avoid using hyperlinks to the other answer. This will help people qho search for your same specific problem find an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

update for anyone with similar problem : turns out this was a known issue with dell BIOS it was patched in a bios update . updating bios fixed it(you can find the update file in dell support page for your model just mv the exe file to /boot/efi folder, reboot to bios and click update bios > flash from file > select the exe file you downloaded > update bios)