# When I fresh install Ubuntu 22.04, after restart it says "Attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'"

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu, grubrescue

I am install Xubuntu 22.04 on a machine that was just running Kubuntu 18.04 (or maybe 22.04). It worked well.

I then removed the old HD and installed a brand new one. I ran then Xubuntu installer and selected the default option to install on the whole disk. Install went fine then I restarted.

Now when I boot into the machine it says "Attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" and enter grub rescue. I have reinstalled again and arrived at the same result.

When I run the ls command from grub rescue it says...

```
(hd0) (hdo,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (fd0)
```

Can I fix this install, or is this machine borked (or the brand new HD is borked).

Comment: Would you please have a look at these solutions: [What to do when I get an "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" error and Boot Repair does not solve the problem?](https://askubuntu.com/q/397485) and see if they work for you.

Comment: Also `(fd0)` seems to be a USB drive (*probably your installation media*) ... You should remove it before rebooting your system.

Comment: You need to set your initial RAM disk.<br/>Look at my own answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256686/cannot-install-ubuntu-20-04-on-mac-mini-2020/1265490#1265490 that starts with the line "OK so this is what worked for me."

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do, given your situation and the fact that you're trying to solve it quickly: Clone your old drive over your new drive. You'd then have your computer just as it was before and you can take things from there (update?)

1. Create / use a disk image cloning software. I use anacronis TrueImage but that's not a free option. [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) is and here is a [guide](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/clone-your-ssd-or-hard-drive) to help you with this part.
2. Use a USB dongle to connect your old drive to your computer. Both drives will need to be connected to clone your old drive. [Theses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqcAB.png) can be had for less than 20$ and shipped next day if you can't source one at your nearest IT Shop. If your drive isn't SATA you'll need a different USB dongle. Seach for either [NVME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsCLd.png) or [IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnWSG.png) usb dongle/enclosures. *The last one works for both IDE and SATA apparently. Note that I haven't tried any of the parts illustrated. I am merely showing you what to look for as a reference. Prices are from Amazon and in CAD.*
3. Follow the steps described on the guide previously given (Tom's Hardware) to clone your old drive over your new drive.
4. The last part about expanding the partition will be different since it is referring to windows. You'll need to instead follow this [guide](https://pimylifeup.com/ubuntu-resize-partition/)