# Dual boot problem. Before I could dual boot, but now only Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

**My Dual boot is working now. The solution to my problem can be found in the last comment below. Thanks again for the help, @oldfred !**

---

I had a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.4 working before.

When I make a fresh reinstall of Ubuntu 20.4 (this time I choose Home partition,) I lost the dual boot provide by Grabber. I thought the Ubuntu Installer would keep the Dual partition as before.

The worst is that Windows 10 is starting now without the chance to boot on Ubuntu. Please help. Thank you.

My system info, https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vSKsp9dy85/

My setup was as you can see on the picture:

1. ext4 ___Primary ___ /      ___I choose to format this partition
2. ext4 ___ Primary ___ /Home ___I choose to format this partition
3. In the **Device for boot loader installation** option, I choose the **Windows Boot Manager** option. ___I did **NOT** choose to format the partition where Windows Boot Manager was/is located
4. [Fast startup disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S8Xh.png) on Windows
5. **Boot Speed** [Normal] or **disabled** on UEFI
6. **Secure Boot [Disabled]** on UEFI
7. **Boot Mode [UEFI Boot]** selected, instead of (BIOS legacy)
8. I run **chkdsk** on windows. It is all good.
9. I run **defragmentation** on windows. It is all good
10. I've just found in my UEFI that I can run Ubuntu from my HDD. Now in order to run Ubuntu, I have to press F12 to access my UEFI and then go to HDD and press "enter." **OBS.:** When I click enter on my HDD, the first option is Windows; the second option is **ubuntu**, and the third option is **Ubuntu** (with capital later.) **There are 2 Ubuntu options**. It doesn't matter which Ubuntu option I click, the Ubuntu starts.
11. Before I get the Ubuntu normal loading process, I get a black screen with a mesage on the top "**System Boot Order Not Found**."
12. Also, I should say that my WIFI is **not** working. It always worded before.

**My Dual boot is working now. The solution to my problem can be found in the last comment below. Thanks again for the help, @oldfred !**

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vSKsp9dy85/   I will update the main question as well. Please, let me know how to fix it. Thank you, @oldfred !

Comment: You always install grub to a drive/device, not to a partition. With UEFI it then knows to install into the ESP which it looks like it did. Grub only boots working Windows. Can you boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu? Your Windows is 264GB but only has 10GB available. That is too full. Houseclean or move data. Windows NTFS likes 30% free at 10% free, you do not really have room to do a defrag.  Check that Windows fast start up is off, Windows does turn it back on with updates & then grub will not boot it.

Comment: 1- I've been checking **Fast Startup**. It has been **Off**. 
2- Also, **Security Boot is Disabled**.  
3- Windows has been booting directly without stopping by Grub when I turn on the PC. Or from my BIOS (UEFI?), after pressing the F12 button. 
4- Regarding the Grub installation, what I meant to say is that when I installed Ubuntu, on the Partitioning phase, on the last option of the screen, **Device for boot loader installation**, I choose the **Windows Boot Manager** option.
Thank you, @oldfred. I hope with all of that we can fix this issue. Please let me know what to do.

Comment: If installing in UEFI mode choosing the Windows will normally be ok, only because Ubiquity only installs to first ESP. If you choose Windows with a BIOS install, you damage Windows. Have you housecleaned Windows. Is Windows fast start up off (different than UEFI fast boot)?  Grub only boots working Windows, but if fast start up is on, or it needs chkdsk then grub will not boot it.

Comment: **If installing in UEFI mode choosing the Windows will normally be ok...**.
1- If I understand, this part of my installation is okay so. But just to learn, which option should I pick from the dropdown menu, **Device for boot loader installation**?
2- Yes I have **housecleaned my Windows**.
3- Yes, it **fast startup is off**, as you can check the picture.
4- What is chkdsk? And how I would run it?

Comment: 4.1- Also, please, what do you mean by **working windows**? My Windows is booting (in all imaginable ways,) and working fine for me at the endpoint as a user. As always, thank you @oldfred! Please let me know what to do to fix my Ubuntu boot.

Comment: if Windows boots that is good. Chkdsk is Windows file repair system. If using Windows you need to know about that as any abnormal shutdown, often then requires chkdsk. You cannot run chkdsk from Linux, but for ext4 use fsck or e2fsck for file system repairs. With UEFI install combo box does not work. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  Ubiquity installer only installs to first ESP.  In UEFI boot menu, what happens if you choose the 'ubuntu' entry?

Comment: I've just updated my main question. I just found out that I could choose Ubuntu from my UEFI. In my UEFI this option is quite hidden. So I described what happened in my main question. Please have a look and let me know what I can do (now that I can access Ubuntu from my HDD). Perhaps run some program to fix all this mess? As always, thank you @oldfred

Comment: Is UEFI set to only boot in UEFI boot mode? It seems like it is trying to boot in BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode, failing, and then going to UEFI?

Comment: I found this option. Yes, my Boot Mode is set to [**UEFI Mode**]

Comment: Boot script showed USB as default boot. See this or review script. `sudo efibootmgr -v`. You want Ubuntu first & Windows second in boot order. You can reset boot order in UEFI settings (not the menu) or with efibootmgr -o x,y,z command in Ubuntu. See `man efibootmgr` or http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr, this fixed it. Thank you, @oldfred !

Comment: Yes. With **sudo efibootmgr -o xxxx,yyyy,zzzz** I could change the boot order. However, no Grub, and the Windows was starting directly as before. But after send this **bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi** command in a Windows Administrator Command Prompt window, on Windows 10, the Grup appeared for the first time and it has been working fine since.