# Dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu, grub is lost, boot-repair doesn't work

Tags: dual-boot

My computer is thinkpad carbon x1, preinstalled with Win10 and I made it dual boot with ubuntu. A few days ago, the grub doesn't pop up anymore and I was straightly directed to Windows when I turned it on.
I once entered the boot menu and saw Linux-Firmware-Update, so I pressed on it. However, I turned up in Win10 at the end again.

So, I made a new ubuntu live usb and I used boot-repair and the following message pop up

`Please create a ESP partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.`

The following is my report:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vPVgcBBQXH/

Is it a boot problem ? Any ways I can fix it?

Comment: If you updated UEFI, it probably reset some UEFI settings. Check those first. You show bitlocker, is Windows fast start up on. Both may be an issue as then bitlocker may be protecting/blocking access to ESP. Grub only boots working Windows, or Windows that  is not hibernated. Fast start up sets hibernation flag, and Windows updates often turn fast start up back on. If you want bitlocker, you may always have to boot from UEFI boot menu, not grub.

Comment: @oldfred Windows fast start up is not on. And the UEFI settings are checked, secure boot is disabled. Does the boot priority order affects? Coz in the boot priority order, Windows boot manager is on the top of the list.

Comment: System default boots first in boot order. You can change with efibootmgr or in your UEFI settings (not boot menu). See:  `man efibootmgr` and -o option. And examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr