# GRUB menu not showing up properly after windows clean install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub-efi

Okay so my laptop came preinstalled with windows 10, on which I installed ubuntu as well to dual boot, and everything worked fine.

However, I recently also installed Fedora on another partition, and after that installed, I noticed that the grub menu for this(which had all options: fedora, ubuntu, as well as windows), was different than the one previously (different fonts, and boot order). However, it worked fine too.

However, then what I did (which in my opinion affected this) from my windows 10 was to check the "Use original boot configuration" under Selective startup (for some other reason). Upon restarting after this, my original grub menu which used to show up before I installed fedora onto my system showed up, which, however, only has the Ubuntu and Windows 10 options.

Hence, I am unable to boot into my Fedora partition, which I can clearly see it exists using Gparted, as well as Windows 10 disk management.

However, another thing, I performed a clean windows installation(using a usb) on my windows partition, and now I no longer get the grub menu. The only way to boot into ubuntu is to go into startup options when the laptop turns on, and to select ubuntu there. On selecting this, I get presented with the ubuntu boot menu (the one without fedora).

I would appreciate any help, or any way I could educate myself more about how grub works, as I don't know pretty much a lot about it.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Normally to add another install you run `sudo update-grub` But with UEFI, you often have to reset UEFI boot order. `man efibootmgr` and
http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Comment: Okayy, well I was able to get my boot menu to appear again by running `sudo update-grub` and `sudo install grub`. Now my grub menu appears, however it only has Ubuntu and Windows as options, apparently my grub isn't detecting my Fedora.

Comment: I think my fedora install is not bootable or something (i'm not entirely sure what that means, someone else pointed this out on reddit). I don't know how I did it though or what I can do to avoid it in the case I try to reinstall fedora. Would be glad to know more about what this is. By the way, the name for my fedora install partition is `fedora_localhost-live`, which I guess points out that I messed up during installing it I guess.

Comment: Report from Boot-Repair would give use details we need. But often Fedora's default install is LVM - logical volumes. And unless Ubuntu also LVM, not its standard partitions, you do not have the LVM drivers. In Ubuntu add lvm2 driver `sudo apt install lvm2` You may need others. Then mount your LVM in Ubuntu & rerun the `sudo update-grub` You may also be able to copy  grub's boot stanza from Fedora's grub to 40_custom, but still need lvm2.