# Change the boot order to boot Ubuntu first after Windows installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi

I had ubuntu at first and installed windows to work on something, the installation is clean and I can boot both operating systems, the problem I have is that I want to see GRUB (I want ubuntu boot at startup) and not windows but It went vice versa after I installed windows. I can now choose ubuntu from my laptop's BIOS settings and the grub is fixed too by repairing in the live ubuntu environment.
[image]
But how can I choose to ubuntu boot first instead of windows?!

Comment: In UEFI > Boot is where you're supposed to define the priority

Comment: I can't achive my goal with this solution, I can just indicate which devices should boot first, for example flash or something else, isn't it?

Comment: You will need to consult the documentation for your motherboard. Choosing the boot volume or setting boot priority is a feature of your motherboard firmware and is unrelated to any operating system.  The implementation is not consistent between motherboards.

Comment: Most systems support efibootmgr changes. A few like HP will only let you change order in UEFI settings (not the UEFI boot menu). See `man efibootmgr` This shows both delete of old UEFI entries & the change order with efibootmgr -o command option. https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr Note that major updates to Windows may reset UEFI boot order to Windows, just like major updates to grub resets UEFI boot order to Ubuntu/grub. You should always be able to boot any installed system from UEFI boot menu. Grub only boots working Windows.