# Dual boot menu not showing. Ubunutu boot drive does not exist anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, bootloader

I've been running a dual-boot setup with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 for several months now, and everything has been working smoothly. However, I recently encountered an unexpected problem: my boot menu has disappeared, and my computer now automatically boots into Windows 11 without any option to choose Ubuntu. This issue arose just yesterday after I powered off my machine and received an error message stating that the boot drive no longer exists. Unfortunately, I can't recall the exact error message, but I'm certain I didn't perform any actions that would intentionally remove the boot drive. It's possible that an event like installing CUDA about a month ago could be related, but I'm unsure.

In an attempt to resolve the issue, I've restarted my computer and even configured the display settings to show the boot menu from within Windows. Despite these efforts, only Windows 11 is visible in the boot menu.

I'm reaching out here in the hopes that someone might have a solution to this problem or suggestions on how to reinstall Ubuntu without losing the data stored on my Ubuntu system.  I'm also not sure how to troubleshoot this issue, so any assistance on that would be very helpful as well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Both Ubuntu/grub & Windows with major updates or UEFI updates, will reset UEFI boot order to be first or default boot. Can you go into UEFI boot menu (often f12 but varies by vendor, same as you used to boot Ubuntu live installer) and boot Ubuntu entry?

Comment: Ahhh I see! I actually solved the problem by changing the boot order, so Ubuntu would be the first in the boot order.  It actually showed the boot menu after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Ubuntu/grub & Windows with major updates or UEFI updates, will reset UEFI boot order to be first or default boot. Can you go into UEFI boot menu (often f12 but varies by vendor, same as you used to boot Ubuntu live installer) and boot Ubuntu entry?

Just about every brand, but HP support use of efibootmgr to change boot order. Grub also uses efibootmgr when updating boot entries with grub install.
You also can change boot order in UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu), only way with HP.

Check current order & hex number of each entry:

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

Change boot order with efibootmgr, some require all 4 hex char others 1 is ok.

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0,1,2
```

see also

```
man efibootmgr
```

[Change boot order using efibootmgr](http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr)