# Lost Dual Boot after exiting BIOS

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Linux Ubuntu along with Windows 11 as a dual boot. Everything was working fine until I opened up the BIOS and looked it over. Before I closed BIOS, I clicked on "Ignore changes and exit". But something did change! Instead of giving me the option to choose between Windows and Ubuntu when I started the computer, it booted up Windows every time with no option to choose. How do I get my dual boot back?

Comment: Both Windows & Ubuntu/grub on updates may reset UEFI boot order so they are first. Did Windows do an update? You may not even see the update that changes boot order. Can you boot using UEFI boot menu. If HP, you can only change boot order in UEFI/BIOS settings and boot tab. If most other systems you can also use efibootmgr and -o parameter. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr and  `man efibootmgr`
http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Comment: I've noticed that some BIOS/firmwares update instantly for some options (esp. on detail saved to drive/partitions etc), whilst most are not saved until you confirm on exit.. thus your "ignore changes and exit" doesn't always work for some hardware/firmware (and all options). The firmware manual usually warns you of this.

Comment: Thanks, oldfred and guiverc
I used the command:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
given in the link and that did the trick. Back to dual boot now!

Comment: I don't see a button to upvote the answer.