# Dual boot with Windows 10 - how can I stop Windows from erasing GRUB?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows several times, but Windows boot manager (WBM) repeatedly kept erasing GRUB. My solution was to immediately move WBM to a lower booting priority after installing Ubuntu, before WBM can cause any harm. However, I am afraid that once I boot into Windows, WBM will again erase GRUB. What should I do to prevent that?

Comment: Unless using the very old BIOS/MBR configuration where there is only one MBR, the issue is both Windows & Ubuntu/grub with updates will reset boot so that system is first in boot order. You can reset with efibootmgr or in UEFI settings, not UEFI one time boot menu. If old MBR then you may get MBR overwritten. But just need to reset with live installer.

Comment: Thanks! Specific references would be highly appreciated (ideally with recipe I can copy and paste).

Comment: Need to know if BIOS or UEFI? Most systems are UEFI as Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives starting in 2012. You really cannot stop Windows updates from moving an UEFI entry as first, but easy to change order in UEFI or just use one time boot menu to boot Ubuntu and reset boot order. If BIOS not so easy. `man efibootmgr` 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr

Comment: Thanks again! So once I changed boot order and booted to Ubuntu several times - Windows boot manager cannot screw up anything anymore? Just making sure I understand correctly.

Comment: Windows updates may change it to first in boot order. So anytime you boot Windows order may change as it will run updates. If only booting Ubuntu Windows cannot do anything.